# Symfony dependency injection to modify service argument

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to add a prefix to all the doctrine tables based on these pages:
docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/sql-table-prefixes.html and 
stackoverflow.com/questions/7504073/how-to-setup-table-prefix-in-symfony2

I'm also using dependency injection to use the configuration for the prefix definition. symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/definitions.html and symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html

Unfortunatly I'm not able to have the tables prefixed using the value defined in the configuration.
But when I manually change the value of the argument in the service definition, it is working.

My project is hosted here: https://github.com/GrenobleSwing/API

See files:

- src/GS/ApiBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
- src/GS/ApiBundle/EventSubscriber/TablePrefixSubscriber.php
- src/GS/ApiBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php
- src/GS/ApiBundle/DependencyInjection/GSApiExtension.php

Thanks in advance for your help.

Julien

Comment: Think you missed 
 `gs_api` root name here: https://github.com/GrenobleSwing/API/blob/master/src/GS/ApiBundle/DependencyInjection/GSApiExtension.php#L29. If not, what's in `$config`?

Comment: Hi, $config contains the configuration.
var_dump($config['doctrine_table_prefix']) is giving the expected value for the prefix.

Comment: Also, when I try to hard code the prefix in the dependency injection ($def->replaceArgument(0, 'something_');), it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cloned your repository, run app in containers and found out what's wrong.

Remove [that line](https://github.com/GrenobleSwing/API/blob/master/app/config/config.yml#L5).

Why?

Now it loads the same configuration twice, and the one loaded in config was used to register event subscribers for Doctrine. So your modifications inside `GSApiExtension` were omitted.

Checked by myself, and it works now.

Comment: Thanks, I would never found this one.